# One or multiple databases SQLite in Android?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm coding an app in Android where I use a lot of databases in SQLite with the next schema:

```
public class DBUser extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int VERSION_DATABASE = 1;

//Name of the database.
private static final String NAME_DATABASE = "NAMEOFDB.db";

//The creation of the table in SQL.
private static final String TABLE_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE example " +
        "(id INT)";

private static final String TABLE_DATABASE2 = "CREATE TABLE example2 " +
        "(id INT)";

// more tables...

//Constructor.
public DBUser(Context context) {
    super(context, NAME_DATABASE, null, VERSION_DATABASE);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABLE_DATABASE);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_DATABASE2);
    //...
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DATABASE);
    onCreate(db);
}

/****NOW THE METHODS****/
}
```

I've, more or less, 5 or 6 java files where I write differents methods for each database that I create.

I want to know if this is the right way or if I must put all tables in one database and write all methods in only one java file.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no right or wrong as long as performance is good. However I would suggest you use some nosql db as a replacement for SQLite if your data is huge (which seems to be the case here).

Comment: By default I would say one database. I think the main use cases for using multiple databases are when you have long running simultaneous transactions on unrelated data, and maybe if some of your data is publicly available and other is private

Comment: It all depends on your app's concept. If you're using separate databases for different type of data and then further categorizing each type into sub categories by help of tables (within the respective database) then go for multiple databases. Or else use a single database.

Comment: Thanks all for comment, I was afraid of doing something wrong but the nature of my app's drive me to divide the concepts. Anyway, thanks :)